# Perlapi-5.10.1, but it is not installable

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, bugzilla

I have a problem with my Ubuntu installation. I'm new to the Ubuntu environment. I don't know how to resolve this problem. I wanted to install mysql-server on my Ubuntu, but I am stuck with these issues.

Here is the one that I get after `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libwx-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.10.1 but it is not installable
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After that, I tried and run the `sudo apt-get -f install` command in my terminal and I get these:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
language-pack-kde-en libpisock9 thunderbird-locale-en-gb
language-pack-kde-en-base kde-l10n-engb thunderbird-locale-en-us
libcompfaceg1 thunderbird-locale-en libetpan15
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
libwx-perl
The following packages will be upgraded:
libwx-perl
1   upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 326 not upgraded.
1   not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,674 kB of archives.
After this operation, 591 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwx-perl:
libwx-perl depends on perlapi-5.10.1; however:
Package perlapi-5.10.1 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libwx-perl (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
libwx-perl
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I to resolve this issue? I wanted to install Bugzilla on my Ubuntu, but it required MySQL and Apache 2. But because of this problem, I can't install both.

```
aptitude
The program 'aptitude' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo apt-get install aptitude 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
aptitude : Depends: libboost-iostreams1.46.1 (>= 1.46.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libcwidget3 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libept1.4.12 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl but it is not going to be installed
libwx-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.10.1 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


sudo apt-cache policy perlapi
N: Unable to locate package perlapi

sudo apt-get --purge remove libwx-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libwx-perl-processstream-perl : Depends: libwx-perl but it is not going to be installed
padre : Depends: libwx-perl (>= 0.91) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libformat-human-bytes-perl (>= 0.06) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libwx-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.10.1 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

All with the same problem...

Here is my **sources.list** file:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20130213)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

After I execute

```
sudo dpkg --purge libwx-perl
```

this is what I get:

```
sudo dpkg --purge libwx-perl
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libwx-perl:
libwx-perl-processstream-perl depends on libwx-perl.
padre depends on libwx-perl (>= 0.91); however:
Package libwx-perl is to be removed.
dpkg: error processing libwx-perl (--purge):
dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
libwx-perl
```

Further:

```
sudo dpkg --purge libwx-perl-processstream-perl libwx-perl
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libwx-perl-processstream-perl:
padre depends on libwx-perl-processstream-perl (>= 0.29); however:
Package libwx-perl-processstream-perl is to be removed.
dpkg: error processing libwx-perl-processstream-perl (--purge):
dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libwx-perl:
libwx-perl-processstream-perl depends on libwx-perl.
padre depends on libwx-perl (>= 0.91); however:
Package libwx-perl is to be removed.
dpkg: error processing libwx-perl (--purge):
dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
libwx-perl-processstream-perl
libwx-perl
```

Comment: use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`, without argument you'll even have a complete gui. Aptitude is far more advanced for dependency resolutions, take time to learn it! (first install perlapi-5.10.1` with `+` command, and look at broken pkg or unmet dep.

Comment: to get more help, tell if u use pinning, your apt sources list...

Comment: Could you be more specific? Seriously i've had issue in resolving this. Im still a newbie in this. @j-p

Comment: there's another tool on top of apt system wich is àptitude` open a terminal, and run [aptitude (LINK)](https://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude), that's it.

Comment: `apt-cache policy perlapi` command could help you knowing what versions are installable. the version you're needing is in `ubuntu `lucid`, is it the version of your ubuntu?

Comment: The aptitude also need to be installed. I just ran it in my terminal and got this dependency issue still. @j-p

Comment: try to remove `libwx-perl` or try àpt-get autoremove` as suggested or `àpt-get purge libwx-perl` for removing it

Comment: I still got the dependency problem. Why is that? Is my ubuntu totally broken? @j-p

Comment: have you process a dist upgrade? that doesn't seem so broken, udate your question with your actual outputs, and what you succed so far

Comment: is libwx-perl removed?

Comment: I have done all that and had updated my question @j-p

Comment: I asked you if you have done a dist-upgrade recently (not tooday) because it's usualy a source of some problems...

Comment: I think i may have done that several days ago because of this dependency problems. Sorry. Maybe i misunderstood you there. @j-p

Comment: Show your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, your `/etc/apt/preferences`. (Im on debian, not sure it's exactly at the same place, you may find sources.list by issuing a `locate sources.list`

Comment: Wait. i wanna update my question again. @j-p

Comment: Also, have you done recently a `apt-get update`, it's important to do so each time you wants to deal with repositories, it will sync your local db with the one on the ubuntu servers

Comment: have you installed ssh? maybe I may connect to your PC from mine if you give me your ip

Comment: Yes i'd also done the update couple days ago i think. I have updated my question. @j-p

Comment: Try `dpkg --purge libwx-perl` and tell me...(dpkg is the level just below apt)

Comment: wait. i update to my question @j-p

Comment: continue with `dpkg --purge` following the error message: first: dpkg --purge `libwx-perl-processstream-perl`. Once all those package removed, do `apt-get install -f` to be sure no prob left, `apt-get update` to sync with depot, and finaly `apt-get dist-upgrade` to be sure all your package are from the precise ubuntu. there is a also a `force` option to dpkg, but dont use it unless nothing else left

Comment: Install aptitude as soon as you can, and use it to install apache and mysql

Comment: `apt-cache` is also very usefull

Comment: But i still have error with the **dkpg --purge libwx-perl-processstream-perl** . The same as to remove the **libwx-perl** @j-p

Comment: put both packages in the same command `dkpg --purge libwx-perl-processstream-perl libwx-perl`

Comment: and if other packages still complains, add them to th purge command :-)

Comment: Still have the same problem. I think this is totally broken? no? 
@j-p

Comment: let me see the output of your last command

Comment: `dpkg --force-help` will give you the abbility to throw those package away, but pay attention to only remove libwx-perl dependencies

Comment: I have updated what you've asked for @j-p So do i need to use the **force**?

Comment: add `padre` to the purge, and if another package depends on `padre` remove it to, and so on. If no other solution is left, yes, you'll may use `force`

Comment: Wait, i'll try first @j-p

Comment: I've done removing all of that you told me. Does that resolve my issue? @j-p

Comment: Once all those package removed, do apt-get install -f to be sure no prob left, apt-get update to sync with depot, and finaly apt-get dist-upgrade to be sure all your package are from the precise ubuntu. Install `aptitude` then àptitude install mySql`

Comment: Thanks man. Your the best. I think this will resolve the issue with the dependency problem. Really appreciate it man @j-p